# Emacs Melpa: Package not found

Tags: emacs, melpa

I run the following command (M-x):

```
Install package: haskell-mode
```

Then I get the error:

```
[No match]
```

My `.emacs` is:

```
(require 'package)
(custom-set-variables
 ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(package-archives
   (quote
    (("gnu" . "http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")
     ("melpa-stable" . "http://stable.melpa.org/packages/")))))
(package-initialize)
```

And I ran also `M-x package-refresh-contents`.

How can I debug this error?

Answer (score 0):

I removed "rm -rf" the dir "~/.emacs.d/" then it worked.

Comment: IMPORTANT NOTE: This will delete your whole config, please be careful if you didn't save it elsewhere